# How to split js string if that already contain comma?

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have problem when split value by comma in js file. In my index.php file, I get name from database and use json_encode() to return data like this,

```
<?php
$sql = "select id,name from my_table where id='$id'";
    $query = mysql_db_query($dbname,$sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $arr['id'][] = $id;
        $arr['name'][] = '"'$ans.'"';
    }
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

In my js file, I get this value by using JSON.parse. Here is my js file.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var arr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            extract(arr);
            var name_var = name.toString().split(',');
            alert(name_var);
            }
        };     
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://myurl/index.php?t="+Math.random(),true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader( "Pragma", "no-cache" );
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader( "Cache-Control", "no-cache" );
    xmlhttp.send(); 

function extract(variable) {
    for (var key in variable) {
        window[key] = variable[key];
    }
}
```

This js is work if response data haven't comma like this

```
"name one","name two","name three","name four"
```

But I got the problem if response data have comma (`"name one","name two,five","name three,six","name four"`), it split to

`"name one"`, `"name two` , `five"` , `"name three` , `six"` , `"name four"`

Its problem for me. I want to change it to like this

`"name one"` , `"name two,five"` , `"name three,six"` , `"name four"`

And I also want to remove double quote from all of the string.

I already try a lot of time to solve that problem. But doesn't work. I very appreciate for any help.

Comment: What is the exact response from server?

Comment: Check if by changing `$arr['name'][] = '"'$ans.'"';` **==>** `$arr['name'][] = $ans;` removes extra quotes, then you can use `JSON.parse()` to get object from string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to get the response in proper format is to send it in the same format from the server.

Try changing `$arr['name'][] = '"'$ans.'"';` to `$arr['name'][] = $ans;` so that all the strings will be added to the array without extra quotes and on client side when the response is get use `JSON.parse(response)` to get the JSON object from the string representation.

---

**If the response format cannot be changed**(*third-party APIs or any other reason*), then you can use JavaScript string methods.

You can use [`String#substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to remove extra quotes and [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split the string by comma which is not inside quotes.

1. `str.substring(1, str.length - 1)`: Removes first and last character from the string, thus removing first and last quotes
2. `.split(/"\s*,\s*"/)`: Split the string by `"` followed by any number of spaces then `,` and then any number of spaces and then quote. Splitting by `","` with any number of spaces in between `"` and `,`.

```js
var str = '"name one" , "name two,five", "name three,six" , "name four"';
var arr = str.substring(1, str.length - 1).split(/"\s*,\s*"/);

console.log(arr);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4) + '</pre>');;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now, it work. And can you please explain this code a little because I'm a newbie in web development.

Comment: @NightMare The code is explained in the points above it, `substring` to remove first and last quotes and `split` to split the string by `","`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add square brackets and utilize JSON parser to do this:

```
var s = '"name one", "name two , five" , "name three , six" , "name four"';

var arr = JSON.parse('[' + s + ']');

console.log(arr[0]); // name one
console.log(arr[2]); // name three , six
```